# Completeness of Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I wanna to prove the completeness of Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ equipped with the induced topology from a set of seminnorms
$$\|f(x)\|_{\alpha,\beta}=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}}|x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}f(x)|$$

A Cauchy sequence in Schwartz space is a sequence of $\{f_{i}\}$ such that 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\|f_{i}(x)-f_{j}(x)\|_{\alpha,\beta}=0 \quad\quad \forall i,j\gt k, \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}^{n}$$

Since the seminorms are uniform norm, for each $\alpha,\beta$, there must be a pointwise limit function $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that

$$x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}f_{i}(x)\to f_{\alpha,\beta}(x) \quad as \quad i\to\infty$$

My question is how I can show that there must be a function $f(x)\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that for each $\alpha,\beta$, $x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}f(x)=f_{\alpha,\beta}(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your convergence is uniform. For a sequence of differentiable functions $\{f_n\}$, if $\{f'_n\}$ converges uniformly, and $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges for some $x$, then $f_n\to f$ and $f_n'\to f'$.

Comment: what you meant was : if $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $f'$ and $f_n(x_0) \to f(x_0)$ then $f_n \to f$ (not always uniformely, but $g_n(x) = f_n(x) / (1+|x|)$ should converge uniformly to $g(x) = f(x) / (1+|x|)$)

Comment: @user1952009 $f$ need not to be previously given. Its differentiability is automatic.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't understand why you care about that $g_{n}(x)$ should converge uniformly to $g(x)$ in this question?

Comment: @QiyuWen Thanks for your tips, I guess I get your point.

Comment: This is a typical limit and differentiation technique. By induction, we can get a limit function $f(x)$ such that $f_{i}^{(n)}(x)\to f^{(n)}(x)$ pointwisely. Then we multiply both sides by a same polynomial $x^{\beta}$